# How to edit enterprise custom field for task from project web app

Tags: project, ms-project

I have created multiple enterprise custom fields for my organization at the task level.  Now I want to edit those fields.  One field is a custom "Confirmed" flag (I know one already exists but we need our own version.)

How can I edit that flag now?  I see you can do this at the project level but it appears I can only display it at the task level.  This is for Project 2013 online.  I know how to do it in the desktop version, just not the online version.

Comment: It appears that I can edit the flag with a Yes/No dropdown list *if* the project is checked out.  Now I can change it but having trouble saving the project again, is timing out.  I think that may be a dev server issue, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You edit enterprise custom fields from the PWA settings screen.  If it's a flag it's a yes/no on/off "flag".  If you want to update the option for that "flag" at the task level you need to create a view in PWA that brings in the field so you can change the field or add the field to a view in Project Professional and update the field that way.